# Windows command pipe to FIND gives error

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

I want to run the following command in a command prompt.

```
net user %USERNAME% /domain | FIND "Full Name"
```

However, I get the error message

```
FIND: Full Name: No such file or directory
```

What am I missing? Is there some environment variable missing or not set?

Comment: As far as I remember `find` is an extra executable `find.exe`; perhaps you (re)moved it unintentionally??

Comment: @aschipfl Both `FIND` and `FINDSTR` are executables and are located at `C:\Windows\System32` & `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` in Windows 7

Comment: Perhaps one of these paths is not included in the system `%PATH%`...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why FIND did not work. I solved the problem by using FINDSTR instead.

```
net user %USERNAME% /domain | FINDSTR "Full Name"
```

Comment: You are aware that ` FINDSTR "Full Name"` finds  `"Full" or "Name"` aren't you? if you want to find  `"Full Name"` you'd need  FINDSTR /c:"Full Name"